TinyTDS Login failed when TSQL connects -
I have a RoR API only app:
gem 'rails', '~> 7.0.8'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '7.0.7'
gem 'composite_primary_keys', '14.0.9'
gem 'tiny_tds', '2.1.7'

The ubuntu server connects just fine to a SQL Server 2016 server with tiny_tds.
Now I am trying to connect it to a SQL Server 2019 server.
I tried with a dataserver, and host/port.
TSQL works just fine. When trying with TinyTds I get

/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/tiny_tds-2.1.7/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:60:in connect': Login failed for user 'UN'. (TinyTds::Error)`

irb(main):033:2* ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection({:adapter=>"sqlserver",
irb(main):034:2*        :encoding=>"utf8",
irb(main):035:2*        :mode=>"dblib",
irb(main):036:2*        :pool=>5,
irb(main):037:2*        :reconnect=>true,
irb(main):038:2*        :timeout=>350000,
irb(main):039:2*        :username=>"UN",
irb(main):040:2*        :password=>"aU",
irb(main):041:0>        :dataserver=> "ccsServer", :database=> "db" })
=>
#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x000056365ad69d40
 @async_executor=nil,
 @automatic_reconnect=true,
 @available=
  #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool::ConnectionLeasingQueue:0x000056365ad69750
   @cond=#<MonitorMixin::ConditionVariable:0x000056365ad696d8 @cond=#<Thread::ConditionVariable:0x000056365ad696b0>, @monitor=#<Monitor:0x000056365ad69c50>>,
   @lock=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x000056365ad69d40 ...>,
   @num_waiting=0,
   @queue=[]>,
 @checkout_timeout=5.0,
 @connection_class=ActiveRecord::Base,
 @connections=[],
 @db_config=
  #<ActiveRecord::DatabaseConfigurations::HashConfig:0x000056365ad6a7b8
   @configuration_hash=
    {:adapter=>"sqlserver",
     :encoding=>"utf8",
     :mode=>"dblib",
     :pool=>5,
     :reconnect=>true,
     :timeout=>350000,
     :username=>"UN",
     :password=>"aU",
     :dataserver=>"ccsServer",
     :database=>"db"},
   @env_name="production",
   @name="primary">,
 @idle_timeout=300.0,
 @lock_thread=false,
 @mon_data=#<Monitor:0x000056365ad69c50>,
 @mon_data_owner_object_id=17320,
 @now_connecting=0,
 @pool_config=
  #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PoolConfig:0x000056365ad6a5b0
   @_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x000056365ad6a448>,
   @connection_class=ActiveRecord::Base,
   @db_config=
    #<ActiveRecord::DatabaseConfigurations::HashConfig:0x000056365ad6a7b8
     @configuration_hash=
      {:adapter=>"sqlserver",
       :encoding=>"utf8",
       :mode=>"dblib",
       :pool=>5,
       :reconnect=>true,
       :timeout=>350000,
       :username=>"UN",
       :password=>"aU",
       :dataserver=>"ccsServer",
       :database=>"db"},
     @env_name="production",
     @name="primary">,
   @pool=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x000056365ad69d40 ...>,
   @role=:writing,
   @shard=:default>,
 @query_cache_enabled=
  #<Concurrent::Map:0x000056365ad69b60 entries=0 default_proc=#<Proc:0x000056365ad698e0 /shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:32>>,
 @reaper=
  #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool::Reaper:0x000056365ad69638 @frequency=60.0, @pool=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x000056365ad69d40 ...>>,
 @role=:writing,
 @shard=:default,
 @size=5,
 @thread_cached_conns=#<Concurrent::Map:0x000056365ad69890 entries=0 default_proc=nil>,
 @threads_blocking_new_connections=0>
irb(main):042:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.active?
/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/tiny_tds-2.1.7/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:60:in `connect': Login failed for user 'UN'. (TinyTds::Error)
irb(main):043:0> exit

$ tsql -S ccsServer -U UN -P aU
locale is "C.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"

So to sum up:

On the same server, a connection to a different MS SQL Server (2016) connects with tiny_tds so it must work
TSQL works fine to connect to the 2019 server with host/port, or dataServer configured in the freetds.conf
The username and password work just fine with TablePlus using SSH into this server
I updated all the gems to latest, and using free_tds version 7.4 (I tried all anyway)
I don't see any logs written for freetds

    [global]
        # TDS protocol version
    tds version = auto

        # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
        # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
    ;   dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
    ;   debug flags = 0xffff

getting in logs:
22:20:31.915545 581001 (token.c:420):looking for login token, got  aa(ERROR)
22:20:31.915552 581001 (token.c:129):tds_process_default_tokens() marker is aa(ERROR)
22:20:31.915556 581001 (mem.c:656):tds_free_all_results()
22:20:31.915560 581001 (token.c:2398):tds_process_info() reading message 18456 from server
22:20:31.915569 581001 (token.c:2493):tds_process_info() calling client msg handler
22:20:31.915573 581001 (dbutil.c:75):_dblib_handle_info_message(0x7fcd04059e30, 0x7fccf4414720, 0x7fcd0d365320)
22:20:31.915577 581001 (dbutil.c:76):msgno 18456: "Login failed for user 'UN'."
22:20:31.915582 581001 (dblib.c:5940):dbgetuserdata(0x7fccf5ba7d70)
22:20:31.915587 581001 (dblib.c:5940):dbgetuserdata(0x7fccf5ba7d70)
22:20:31.915591 581001 (dblib.c:5040):dbdead(0x7fccf5ba7d70) [alive]

OK getting even weirder, this app connects to multiple database (it has always, just up until now all the databases were on the same host/port). Now there is an additional database on a new host/port, and when I connect with TinyTds specifying the new host/port (manually, or with it's own database.yml key, or with ActiveRecord::Base.connection) it keeps overriding the host/port with the other server that was there until now. How do I know this? I used the new host/port, but the old username/password and the connection worked. I've been doing all this in the rails console.
Now what?!!?!? I need both, and want to specify a host/port.

Aside... SQL Server keeps its own account store for SQL Logins so the username and password you use for SSH may not be usable in SQL Server.

If you have admin access to the SQL Server instance can you see its ERRORLOG? Look for the Error 18456 Login Failure events, take note of their State number(s), and compare them against those published at MSSQLSERVER_18456 to determine the cause of the login failure.

I use TablePLus to SSH into the production server that is on the same network as this server so there are no firewall issues. This uses my ssh key, and then I use database credentials to ssh into it. This server, and the other are hosted on azure, but it is not a database managed server, you login with regular username and password (which worked with TSQL). I am looking at the server logs, if I connect with TSQL i see a log, no logs for attempts made with tiny_tds @AlwaysLearning

Also nothing hitting my server with these either ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("#{Rails.env}_ccs".to_sym) -- this is listed out in my database.yml. Again this connection connects to the old server which would be Rails.env.to_sym

Thanks @dale-k for fixing up my coding blocks. I am terrible at this.

Ah, seems you've already been hitting the next issue I was going to suggest: are you connecting to the right server? That would also explain why you're not seeing 18456 login failures on the new server. I would suggest trawling your freetds.conf files to see if you have aliases configured for ccsServer that are still referencing the old instance. Or maybe customisations in your hosts file.

Nothing doing, freetds.conf only has new server configured, i even replaced the production key in the database.yml with the new server and its still not using it. But crazy thing is eventually I want to be able to toggle between both servers depending on a db_key passed in, and it worked fine when we were all on one host, and it should theoretically work fine with two servers.

ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES HARD CODED INTO PRODUCTION, I think this is the culprit and I feel terribly stupid. How many hours??!
